# how to change items of two comboboxes with same index -java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

I have two comboboxes, one for choosing 'number' and another one for choosing 'name'. When I select an item from number ,the name must be changed according to the index of number and vice versa`

[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF2lr.png)

```
 private void nameItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
    {                                                
         int i = name.getSelectedIndex();
         number.setSelectedIndex(i);
        //It will changes number according to name  
        //Used ItemEvent        
    }  



private void numberItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) 
   {                                                
         int i = number.getSelectedIndex();
         name.setSelectedIndex(i);
         //It will change name according to number
         //used ItemEvent
    }
```

These codes are making exceptions because both are using ItemStateChanged event..So suggest another method..

Comment: Please provide more information, including precisely what compiler error message you're seeing. Also, if you want number and name to be closely associated with a one-to-one association, why not display them together in one JComboBox, or in a JTable?

Comment: Why not combine your name and number to a common class, and have one combo box with these objects?  Surely that will make life easier...

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be giving your class two methods with the same signature, and the compile won't allow you to do this. If so, then the solution is not to do this. If you absolutely need two JComboBoxes tightly tied together in a one-to-one relationship, something that I **don't** recommend that you do, then either give each combo box its own ChangeListener, or better yet, have them share the same model but use a different renderer for each.

For a more specific answer, please update your question, including posting a valid [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (please check out the links).

For example, here are two JComboBoxes that share the same model, a model that holds "Customer" objects. The Customer class has only two private instance fields, an int "id" field and a String "name" field. So again both combo boxes are holding the **same** data.

But they display the data differently by using different cell renderers, one that shows only the id, and the other that shows just the name. You only need to add a ChangeListener to one, and it will be activated if either combobox's selection is changed, since changing one changes the other (again they share the same model).

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LinkedComboEg extends JPanel {
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<Customer> comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<Customer> idCombo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);
    private JComboBox<Customer> nameCombo = new JComboBox<>(comboModel);

    public LinkedComboEg() {
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1001, "Doc"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1002, "Donald Trump"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1003, "Bashful"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1004, "Grumpy"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1005, "Sneezy"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1006, "Happy"));
        comboModel.addElement(new Customer(1007, "Sleepy"));

        idCombo.setRenderer(new IdRenderer());
        nameCombo.setRenderer(new NameRenderer());
        nameCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1); // none selected to start

        // add an item listener to just one combo box. Either will do
        idCombo.addItemListener(ie -> {
            Customer selection = (Customer) ie.getItem();
            if (ie.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED && selection != null) {
                System.out.printf("Selected id: %s;   Selected name: %s%n", 
                        selection.getId(),
                        selection.getName());
            }
        });

        add(new JLabel("ID Number:"));
        add(idCombo);
        add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(nameCombo);
    }

    // renderer to add to the idCombo so that it displays the Customer's ID
    private class IdRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            } else {
                value = ((Customer) value).getId();
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }

    // renderer to add to the nameCombo so that it displays the Customer's Name
    private class NameRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
                boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
            if (value == null) {
                value = "";
            } else {
                value = ((Customer) value).getName();
            }
            return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        LinkedComboEg mainPanel = new LinkedComboEg();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Linked Combo Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Customer(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Customer other = (Customer) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```